# What svn command would list all the files modified on a branch?

Tags: svn

In svn, I have a branch which was created, say at revision 22334. Commits were then made on the branch.

How do I get a list of all files that were changed on the branch compared to what's on the trunk? I do not want to see files that were changed on the trunk between when the branch was created and "now".

Comment: I come back to this question rather often and the most helpful answer is the one deleted from @AndrewMedico , with `svn log` :-D

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This will do it I think:

```
svn diff -r 22334:HEAD --summarize <url of the branch>
```

Comment: Thanks. I even didn't know from what revision my branch is, so I do `svn log <url of the branch> | tail` to get the smallest revision number.

Comment: After running this to get a summary of all of the changes, if you want to review each change you have made on your branch, you can use `svn diff -r 22334` (note that a diff to the HEAD is not specified). This will diff to your local working copy and allow you to make changes to it from within your diff application.

Answer (score 51):

You can also get a quick list of changed files if thats all you're looking for using the status command with the -u option

```
svn status -u
```

This will show you what revision the file is in the current code base versus the latest revision in the repository. I only use diff when I actually want to see differences in the files themselves.

There is a good tutorial on svn command here that explains a lot of these common scenarios: [SVN Command Reference](http://web.archive.org/web/20110316170621/http://www.duchnik.com/tutorials/vc/svn-command-reference)

Comment: `svn status` will only show you local modifications.  the OP was looking for how to see all the file changes that have been committed to their branch since it was created from trunk.

Answer (score 32):

You can use the following command:

```
svn status -q
```

According to [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html):

`With --quiet (-q), it prints only summary information about locally modified items.`

WARNING: The output of this command only shows your modification. So I suggest to do a `svn up` to get latest version of the file and then use `svn status -q` to get the files you have modified.

Comment: Short but sweet answer.

Comment: @maskarih flawless answer!

Answer (score 14):

This will list only modified files:

```
svn status -u | grep M
```

Comment: svn status only shows local workarea modifications.  this is not answering the original question in regards to all changes on the branch, after it's creation.

Comment: and files that contain `M` in the name

Comment: svn status -u | grep ^M

Comment: I use status -u | grep "M "

Answer (score 2):

```
echo You must invoke st from within branch directory
SvnUrl=`svn info | grep URL | sed 's/URL: //'`
SvnVer=`svn info | grep Revision | sed 's/Revision: //'`
svn diff -r $SvnVer --summarize $SvnUrl
```

Answer (score 1):

-u option will display including object files if they are added during compilation.

So, to overcome that additionally you may use like this.

```
svn status -u | grep -v '\?'
```

Answer (score 1):

`svn log -q -v` shows paths and hides comments.  All the paths are indented so you can search for lines starting with whitespace. Then pipe to `cut` and `sort` to tidy up:

`svn log --stop-on-copy -q -v | grep '^[[:space:]]'| cut -c6- | sort -u`

This gets all the paths mentioned on the branch since its branch point. Note it will list deleted and added, as well as modified files.  I just used this to get the stuff I should worry about reviewing on a slightly messy branch from a new dev.

Answer (score 1):

I do this as a two-step process.  First, I find the version that was the origin of the branch.  From within the checkout of the branch:

`svn log --stop-on-copy |tail -4`

`--stop-on-copy` tells SVN to only operate on entries after the branch.  `tail` gets you the last log entry, which is the one that contains the branch information. The number that begins with an 'r' is the revision at which you branched. Then, use `svn diff` to find changes since that version:

`svn diff -r <revision at which you branched>:head --summarize`

the --summarize option shows a file list only, without the actual diff contents, similar to the 'svn status' output.  If you want to see the actual diff, just remove the `--summarize` option.