# Cleartool lsco -avo -cview equivalent on SVN

Tags: svn, cleartool

What is the equivalent command on SVN as `cleartool lsco -avo -cview -me`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `svn status` I believe.

```
cleartool lsco -avo -cview -me
```

Is for listing all currently checked out files (`lsco`) in the current view (`-cview`), by the current user (`-me`)

If you were to do an `svn status` in an svn workspace (which is the equivalent of a ClearCase snapshot view), you would get the current modified files as well.
See "[svn list of files that are modified in local copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168464/svn-list-of-files-that-are-modified-in-local-copy)" for other options.
For instance, on Windows:

```
svn status -u | grep '^M'
```

(for more on the `-u` option, see "[What svn command would list all the files modified on a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160370/what-svn-command-would-list-all-the-files-modified-on-a-branch)")

---

The [OP beyonddc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287281/beyonddc) has a more advanced version of that command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && svn status | grep '^M'" \;
```

Comment: aahh... thanks for your hint.

Here's what I end up with `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && svn status | grep '^M'" \;`